# Rolling Mean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I have this initial DataFrame in Pandas

```
                  A             B             C       D          E
    0               23       2015             1      14937     16.25
    1               23       2015             1      19054      7.50
    2               23       2015             2      14937     16.75
    3               23       2015             2      19054     17.25
    4               23       2015             3      14937     71.75
    5               23       2015             3      19054     15.00
    6               23       2015             4      14937     13.00
    7               23       2015             4      19054     37.75
    8               23       2015             5      14937      4.25
    9               23       2015             5      19054     18.25
    10              23       2015             6      14937     16.50
    11              23       2015             6      19054      1.00
```

If I want to obtain this result, how could I do it?

```
           A             B             C       D          E
0               23       2015             1      14937     NaN
1               23       2015             2      14937     NaN 
2               23       2015             2      14937     16.6
3               23       2015             1      14937     35.1
4               23       2015             2      14937     33.8
5               23       2015             3      14937     29.7
6               23       2015             4      14937     11.3
7               23       2015             4      19054     NaN
8               23       2015             5      19054     NaN
9               23       2015             5      19054     13.3
10              23       2015             6      19054     23.3
11              23       2015             6      19054     23.7
12              23       2015             6      19054     19.0
```

I tried a GroupBy but I dind't get it

```
DfMean = pd.DataFrame(DfGby.rolling(center=False,window=3)['E'].mean())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) (need at least [pandas 0.18.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations)):

```
s = df.groupby('D').rolling(3)['E'].mean()
print (s)
D        
14937  0           NaN
       2           NaN
       4     34.916667
       6     33.833333
       8     29.666667
       10    11.250000
19054  1           NaN
       3           NaN
       5     13.250000
       7     23.333333
       9     23.666667
       11    19.000000
Name: E, dtype: float64
```

Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `D` with [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for same order for matching output:

```
df = df.set_index('D', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)

df['E'] = s
```

Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and reorder columns:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0).sort_values(['D','C'])
df = df[['A','B','C','D','E']]

print (df)
     A     B  C      D          E
0   23  2015  1  14937        NaN
2   23  2015  2  14937        NaN
4   23  2015  3  14937  34.916667
6   23  2015  4  14937  33.833333
8   23  2015  5  14937  29.666667
10  23  2015  6  14937  11.250000
1   23  2015  1  19054        NaN
3   23  2015  2  19054        NaN
5   23  2015  3  19054  13.250000
7   23  2015  4  19054  23.333333
9   23  2015  5  19054  23.666667
11  23  2015  6  19054  19.000000
```